# How is Nesterov's Accelerated Gradient Descent implemented in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

The documentation for [`tf.train.MomentumOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MomentumOptimizer) offers a `use_nesterov` parameter to utilise Nesterov's Accelerated Gradient (NAG) method.

However, NAG requires the gradient at a location other than that of the current variable to be calculated, and the `apply_gradients` interface only allows for the current gradient to be passed. So I don't quite understand how the NAG algorithm could be implemented with this interface.

The documentation says the following about the implementation:

> `use_nesterov`: If True use Nesterov Momentum. See [Sutskever et al.,
>   2013](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/sutskever13.pdf). This
>   implementation always computes gradients at the value of the
>   variable(s) passed to the optimizer. Using Nesterov Momentum makes the
>   variable(s) track the values called `theta_t + mu*v_t` in the paper.

Having read through the paper in the link, I'm a little unsure about whether this description answers my question or not. How can the NAG algorithm be implemented when the interface doesn't require a gradient function to be provided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

TF's implementation of Nesterov is indeed an approximation of the original formula, valid for high values of momentum.

**Details**

This is a great question. In the paper, the NAG update is defined as

```
vt+1 = μ.vt - λ.∇f(θt + μ.vt)
θt+1 = θt + vt+1
```

where `f` is our cost function, `θt` our parameters at time `t`, `μ` the momentum, `λ` the learning rate; `vt` is the NAG's internal accumulator.

The main difference with standard momentum is the use of the gradient at `θt + μ.vt`, *not* at `θt`. But as you said, tensorflow only uses gradient at `θt`. So what is the trick?

Part of the trick is actually mentioned in the part of the documentation you cited: the algorithm is tracking `θt + μ.vt`, *not* `θt`. The other part comes from an approximation valid for high value of momentum.

Let's make a slight change of notation from the paper for the accumulator to stick with tensorflow's definition. Let's define `at = vt / λ`. The update rules are changed slightly as

```
at+1 = μ.at - ∇f(θt + μ.λ.at)
θt+1 = θt + λ.at+1
```

(The motivation for this change in TF is that now `a` is a pure gradient momentum, independent of the learning rate. This makes the update process robust to changes in `λ`, a possibility common in practice but that the paper does not consider.)

If we note `ψt = θt + μ.λ.at`, then

```
at+1 = μ.at - ∇f(ψt)
ψt+1 = θt+1 + μ.λ.at+1
    = θt + λ.at+1 + μ.λ.at+1
    = ψt + λ.at+1 + μ.λ.(at+1 - at)
    = ψt + λ.at+1 + μ.λ.[(μ-1)at - ∇f(ψt)]
    ≈ ψt + λ.at+1
```

This last approximation holds for strong values of momentum, where `μ` is close to 1, so that `μ-1` is close to zero, and `∇f(ψt)` is small compared to `a` — this last approximation is more debatable actually, and less valid for directions with frequent gradient switch.

We now have an update that uses the gradient of the current position, and the rules are pretty simple — they are in fact those of standard momentum.

However, we want `θt`, not `ψt`. This is the reason why we subtract `μ.λ.at+1` to `ψt+1` just before returning it — and to recover `ψ` it is added again first thing at the next call.

Comment: Great answer, cheers. I'll mark this as the answer as it gives more insight than mine.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't see any info on this online, and the linked paper certainly wasn't helpful, so I had a look at the [unit tests for `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/training/momentum_test.py), from which I can see tests for the implementation of both classic momentum and NAG modes.

### Summary

```
var = var + accum * learning_rate * momentum
accum = accum * momentum + g
var = var - learning_rate * accum
var = var - accum * learning_rate * momentum
```

where `accum` starts at 0 and is updated at every step. The above is a modified version of the formulation in the unit test, and I find it a bit confusing. Here is the same set of equations arranged with my interpretation of what each of the parameters represent (I could be wrong though):

```
average_grad_0 = accum # previous rolling average
average_grad_1 = accum * momentum + g # updated rolling average
grad_diff = average_grad_1 - average_grad_0
adjustment = -learning_rate * (grad_diff * momentum + average_grad_1)
var += adjustment
accum = average_grad_new
```

In other words, it seems to me like `tensorflow`'s implementation attempts to guess the "adjusted gradient" in NAG by assuming that the new gradient will be esimated by the current average gradient plus the product of momentum and the change in the average gradient. I'd love to see a proof for this!

What follows is more detail on how the classic and nesterov modes are implemented in `tensorflow` as per the tests.

### Classic Momentum mode

For `use_nesterov=False`, based on the `doTestBasic` function, we have the following initial parameters:

```
learning_rate = 2.0
momentum = 0.9
var_0 = 1.0 # at time 0
grad = 0.1
```

Actually, the above are just the first element of the `grads_0` and `vars_0` arrays, but I'll just focus on a single value. For the subsequent timesteps, we have

```
var_1 = 1.0 - (0.1 * 2.0)
var_2 = 1.0 - (0.1 * 2.0) - ((0.9 * 0.1 + 0.1) * 2.0)
```

which I'm going to interpret as meaning;

```
var_1 = var_0 - (grad * learning_rate)
var_2 = var_1 - ((momentum * grad + grad) * learning_rate)
```

If we assume that for the purposes of the unit tests `grad_0 == grad_1 == grad` then this makes sense as a formulation of classic momentum.

### Nesterov's Accelerated Gradient (NAG) mode

For `use_nesterov=True`, I had a look at the `_update_nesterov_momentum_numpy` function and the `testNesterovMomentum` test case.

The `_update_nesterov_momentum_numpy` function has the following definition:

```
  def _update_nesterov_momentum_numpy(self, var, accum, g, lr, momentum):
    var = var + accum * lr * momentum
    accum = accum * momentum + g
    var = var - lr * accum
    var = var - accum * lr * momentum
    return var, accum
```

and it is called in the unit tests like this:

```
    for t in range(1, 5):
      opt_op.run()
      var0_np, accum0_np = self._update_nesterov_momentum_numpy(
          var0_np, accum0_np, var0_np * 10, 2.0, 0.9)
```