# nesterov momentum gradient calculation at predicted point

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

In nesterov momentum, the Gradient of the error function with respect to the parameters is calculated at a point different from that where the cost was calculated - that is, the model jumps ahead a bit according to its previous momentum and calculates the gradient there to use in further calculation. My question is, if the loss was calculated at our current point, how can we calculate the gradient at a different point when the loss is unknown? I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774683/how-is-nesterovs-accelerated-gradient-descent-implemented-in-tensorflow), which sort of answers this question, but provides an approximation at best, and one that does not work in all cases. Can someone help me out on how we are supposed to calculate the gradient at a different point without the loss, or if we are just supposed to use the approximation provided above? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code which you currently have?

Comment: @3141 I am not looking at this from a code standpoint (yet, i want to code it out in the end), but more from a formulaic standpoint. How is it that we can calculate the gradient at some point that we do not have the loss at? It doesn't seem to make sense to me, and the TensorFlow implementation uses an approximation, see the link I posted above. I am wondering if the approximation is the standard for this calculation or if there is a better way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I am also very interested in this problem as I want to implement an optimizer that needs many more loss function evaluations. So far the only easy solution is to use a custom model and tailor the `train_step` method. I have sketched this (among other things) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791633/custom-optimizer-with-multiple-loss-function-evaluations). Please let me know what you think.