# Custom optimizer with multiple loss function evaluations

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to implement a custom optimization algorithm for TF models.
I have read the following sources

- [tf documentation on custom optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#creating_a_custom_optimizer_2)
- [tf SGD implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py)
- [keras documentation on custom models](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/)
- [towardsdatascience guide on custom optimizers](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-optimizer-in-tensorflow-d5b41f75644a)

However lot of questions remain.

1. It seems like it is not possible to evaluate the loss function multiple times (for different weight settings) before applying a gradient step, when using the custom optimizer API. For example in a line-search type of algorithm this is necessary.
2. I tried to do all steps manually.

Assume I have setup my model and my optimization problem like this

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras import models

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(15, input_dim=10))
model.add(layers.Dense(20))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

x_train, y_train = get_train_data()
loss = losses.MeanSquaredError()

def val_and_grads(weights):
    model.set_weights(weights)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        val = loss(y_train, model(x_train))

    grads = tape.gradient(val, model.trainable_variables)

    return val, grads

initial_weights = model.get_weights()
optimal_weigths = my_fancy_optimization_algorithm(val_and_grads, initial_weights)
```

However my function `val_and_grads` needs a `list` of weights and returns a `list` of gradients from `my_fancy_optimization_algorithm`s point of view that seems unnatural.

I could warp `val_and_grads` to "stack" the returned gradients and "split" the passed weights like this

```py
def wrapped_val_and_grad(weights):
    grads = val_and_grads(split_weights(weights))
    return stack_grads(grads)
```

however that seems very inefficient.

Anyway, I do not like this approach since it seems that I would loose out out on a lot of the surrounding tensorflow infrastructure (printing of current loss function values and metrics during learning, tensorboard stuff, ...).

3. I could also pack the above in a custom model with a tailored `train_step` like this

```py
def CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
    
        x_train, y_train = data

        def val_and_grads(weights):
            self.set_weights(weights)
        
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                val = loss(y_train, self(x_train))
        
            grads = tape.gradient(val, self.trainable_variables)
            return val, grads

        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables

        old_weights = self.get_weights()
        update = my_fancy_update_finding_algorithm(val_and_grads, self.get_weights()) # this can do multiple evaluations of the model
        self.set_weights(old_weights) # restore the weights

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(update, trainable_vars))
```

Here I would need a accompanying custom optimizer that does nothing else than updating the current weights by adding the `update` (new_weigths = current_weights + update).

I am still unsure if this is the best way to go.

If someone can comment on the snippets and ideas above, guide me to any other resource that I should consider or provide new approaches and other feedback I would be very glad.

Thanks all.

Franz

---

EDIT:
Sadly I did not get any response here so far. Maybe my question is not concrete enough. As a first smaller question:
Given the `model` and `val_and_grads` in the first listing. How would I efficiently calculate the norm of the WHOLE gradient? What I do so far is

```py
import numpy as np
_, grads = val_and_grad(model.get_weights())
norm_grads = np.linalg.norm(np.concatenate([grad.numpy().flatten() for grad in grad]))
```

This surely cannot be the "right" way.